# ERROR while updating Spreadsheet using python, Google Seets API, v4: got multiple values for argument 'range'

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to update a whole spreadsheet using Python, Google Seets API, v4.

I Made a function based on the API to update the database but is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: update_values() got multiple values for argument 'range'
```

The functions are structured in the following way:

```
def update_values(self, range, values):
    '''
    documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values
    values = [
        [
            # Cell values ...
        ],
        # Additional rows ...
    ]
    '''
    body = {
        'values': values
    }
    result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=self.sheet_id,
        range=range,
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        body=body).execute()
    print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('updatedCells')))
```

The execution function is the following:

```
def update(self,values):
    pprint(self.SHEET_NAME[1])
    self.gsheets.update_values(self,
                               range='{}!A1:AD2000'.format(self.SHEET_NAME[1]),
                               values=values
                               )
```

Additional data to understand the code:

```
SHEET_NAME[1]='sheet_x'
```

`gsheets.update_values` is the first function `update_values()` in the class `gsheets`

```
range='{}!A1:AD2000'.format(self.SHEET_NAME[1]
```

Comment: `range` shadows the built-in `range` object, I'd start by changing that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `update_values` is a method and you have an instance of its class in `self.gsheets`. Python adds `self` automatically when an instance method is called. When you call `update_values(self, range=..., ...)` that `self` you put in is actually the second parameter "range". Just leave that parameter out.

```
self.gsheets.update_values(range='{}!A1:AD2000'.format(self.SHEET_NAME[1]),
                           values=values
                           )
```

Comment: I'm not sure. It looks like a JSON string decode issue. Can you print out the JSON itself to see what is wrong? `np.NaN` is a float and is supported by JSON. So, `json.loads("NaN")` works. `"User R\u ^"` looks really strange. It doesn't seem like valid python (a \u unicode escape should have 4 hex characters following) or json. If you can get enough details, this would be a new question for stackoverflow.